# Is "Value Validation in Getter/Setter" good style?

Tags: c++, exception, setter, getter

my Getter/Setter methods check the value, before they set/return it. When the value is invalid, they throw an exception (BadArgumentException or IllegalStateException). This is needed since we initialize all members with invalid values - and so we avoid working with these invalid values ( == getting errors/segfaults/exception in other places).

The benefits are:

- When you receive a member-value from a model, you know that they are valid
- The validity checks are only performed in the model-object
- The value range is defined in the model-object

This seems to be very unusual, since most new team-member first complain about it - even if they agree with  me after I explain it to them.

Question: Is this a good programming style? (Even if it wasts a bit of performance)

**Example Code**:

```
inline bool MyClass::HasGroupID const { return m_iGroupID != 0; }

int MyClass::GetGroupID() const
{
    if( !HasGroupID() )
        throw EPTIllegalStateException( "Cannot access uninitialized group ID!" );

    return m_iGroupID;

}   // END GetGroupID() const

void MyClass::SetGroupID( int iGroupID )
{
    // negative IDs are allowed!
    if( iGroupID != 0 )
        throw EPTBadArgumentException( "GroupID must not be zero!", iGroupID );

    m_iGroupID = iGroupID;

}   // END SetGroupID( int )
```

**Usage**:

```
// in serialization
if( myObject.HasGroupID() )
    rStream.writeAttribute( "groupid", GetGroupID() );

// in de-serialization
try {
    // required attribute - throw exception if value is invalid
    myObject.SetGroupID( rStream.GetIntegerAttribute( "groupid" );
} catch( EPTBadArgumentException& rException )
{
    throw EPTBadXmlAttribute( fileName, rException );
}
```

Comment: it's a very good programming style in most cases. i highly recommend. it's also good if you work with database models etc

Comment: I don't think it is good style to have invalid objects all around. It's a lot better to initialize things to valid values.

Comment: but if you initialize them with valid values and forget a Setter() (e.g. after adding a new member - in the clone method, or during read-in, or in the copy constructor, assignment method, etc) you will mention this very very late (and most of the time you won't know, where the bug comes from). So you will get an exception, and it will be mostly good to reproduce...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's common style, and it's certainly one of the core motivations for getter/setters in the first idea. However, in your particular example, I don't think they make sense and I think that in general there are often better alternatives:

If calling `GetGroupID` raises an exception if `HasGroupID` yields false, then this is a programmer error - so you should probably use an `assert`. In fact, why is it possible to have an object without a group ID in the first place? This sounds like a slightly inelegant design.

Furthermore, if only non-zero IDs are valid, then you should try to enforce this restriction even earlier, using a dedicated type. That way, all the code dealing with group IDs can be sure that the IDs are valid (in fact, the compiler enforces this!) and you can't possibly forget to check in some place. Consider:

```
class GroupID {
public:
    explicit GroupID( int id ) : m_id( id ) {
        if ( m_id == 0 ) {
            throw EPTBadArgumentException( "GroupID must not be zero!", m_id );
        }
    }

    // You may want to allow implicit conversion or rather use an explicit getter
    operator int() const { return m_id; }
};
```

Using this, you can just write

```
void MyClass::SetGroupID( GroupID id )
{
    // No error checking needed; we *know* it's valid, because it's a GroupID!
    // We can also use a less verbose variable name without losing readability
    // because the type name reveals the semantics.
    m_iGroupID = id;

} // END SetGroupID( int )
```

In fact, since group IDs are now a dedicated type, you could rename your function to just `Set` and use overloads. So you have `MyClass::Set(UserID)` and `MyClass::Set(GroupID)` and so on.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Some remarks: (1) in my team we ban asserts, since we want to handle programmer errors with exceptions (2) group-ID is an optional element - so it also can be absent (see `HasGroupID()`) (3) we initialize all members as invalid, to avoid accessing un-initialized members (--> exception)

Comment: the approach of creating a non-virtual class GroupID with inline methods is great (performance, memory footprint) and I used it often, but I cannot create a new class for every parameter!

Comment: @Charly: Handling programming errors with exceptions sounds a lot like *we don't solve bugs, we push them under the rug and hope they don't crawl out*. The different between asserts and exceptions is that exceptions can be caught and ignored but programming errors should never be ignored. You should reconsider the use of asserts.

Comment: @Charly: For optional elements consider using a prepacked *optional* tool, like for example, `boost::optional` as that will remove a good amount of boiler plate code and make things simpler to maintain. Will you remember months from now for each one of your parameters what value means *not present*? Will you always have such a value? (Note: `boost::optional` has greater memory and runtime costs, but it is semantically more explicit and thus easier to maintain)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, this is one of most important purposes of the getter/setter idea. Encapsulation by itself is uncomfortable - writing straightforward code that just accesses member variables is easier. But by encapsulation you can restrict access to the variables: sanity-check the values, synchronize access through mutexes, bind changes to triggers, log them and so on.

Normally, in the most basic case none of this is necessary, but at a later time a surprising number of these sprout out, and if you've been fiddling with class members, there's a lot of code to fix. If you used simple getters/setters everywhere from moment one, now you can add anything you need to them.

Comment: If you started with getters and setters from day one, but only now are adding validation checks that throw, you're breaking your previous contract. Code that already existed may now be broken. The fact that it still compiles doesn't make that a good thing.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: if it was documented all along (for example) that `Set` must only be called with a valid value, and that `Get` must not be called before `Set`, then adding exceptions thrown in situations that were always forbidden doesn't break the previous contract. So it's partly a question of whether the contract was designed in the first place with these invalid values in mind. If you want to come along later and decide that a value that used to be valid (if useless) is now invalid, that's much harder.

Answer (score 0):

i would agree with your new team members. For me its not verry usual, but if you have to and it's the only way, you should do it.
I would try to make objects which are filled with consitent data.
 You can reach this by checking the values in your constructor and offering no setter.
First i excuse for writing C# but my C++ is a littble bit rusty :-)

```
class MyClass{

    private int groupId; 

    public MyClass(int groupId) {
        if(groupId ==0){
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("groupId",groupId,"Group Id must be >0");
        }
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public int GroupId{ 
        get{ 
             return groupId;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can be sure that a Class MyClass is only initialized if all Properties match their requirements. You can Implement a constructor wich takes a MyClass Instance and clones all Values to create cloned objects.
If you need to change the properties make a Interface and define a `MyClassChangeable`

```
public class Programm {
    static void main(string[] args) {
        IMyClass myClassChangable = new MyClassChangable(-123);
        try {
            MyClass correctMyClass = new MyClass(myClassChangable);
            useThisClass(correctMyClass);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Display to user or something
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    static void useThisClass(MyClass myClass) {
        //this is alway correct!
        int groupId = myClass.GroupId;

    }
}

interface IMyClass {
    int GroupId { get; }
}

class MyClass : IMyClass {
    private int groupId;

    public MyClass(int groupId) {
        if (groupId == 0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("groupId", groupId, "Group Id must be >0");
        }
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public MyClass(IMyClass instance)
        : this(instance.GroupId) {
    }

    #region Implementation of IMyClass

    public int GroupId {
        get { return groupId; }
    }

    #endregion
}


public class MyClassChangable : IMyClass {
    private int groupId = 0;

    public MyClassChangable() {

    }

    public MyClassChangable(int groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    #region Implementation of IMyClass

    public int GroupId {
        get { return groupId; }
        set { groupId = value; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You now can use a class however you want to use it, and than "check" it at only one point (so a single point of exception). In the "BusinessCore" you are using the MyClass which has always the right values. So no Exceptions and no OutOfBounds!

Hope i could help, please contact me if you have further questions or if something is wrong, would be glad learning!
I would enjoy getting feedback to my idea!

Comment: (1) I agree - but what if the GroupID is optional? So there are valid objects, which return `false` on `HasGroupID()`

Comment: (2) Your point would be better visible, if your classes have two or more members. So changing one member, you will copy the class into the MyClassChangeable and afterwards copy it back to MyClass?? The second copy will do the evaluation... and all for changing one parameter? Because for initially setting a member you don't need the MyClassChangeable.

Comment: (1) If one Paramter is Optional: In my opinion you should make a new Class/Interface for this Parameter so you can be sure, that this paramter is correctly set. For example: Class "Car" has Property "Engine" if "Engine" == null Method "Start()" would fail. Becaus you don't know which parameters has to be set, any other Method can also fail. So the consumer of the Class "Car" has to check if every property is set right. This leads to many checks in consumer code. Solution would be a class "CarBody", with no Property "Engine" and no Method "Start" and a class "Car" inherited from "CarBody"

Comment: The consumer only Takes instances of type "Car" and can therefore be sure, that method "start" doesn't throw an exception due to lack of an property.

Comment: (2) The question is, do you have to change a Paramter on this instance in your BusinessCore, and why don't create a new Instance of MyClass. Changing the property of the Instance in your method, also changes it for every other Method in every other thread or even process. For example:This Instance could be used in a "for" loop and suddendly the count is changed by your method. From my point: I don't want a method to change a property implicit by doing it on the reference. If a method has to change a  property it can return a new instance with the changed properties.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding validation: it's perfectly usual for the Setter to validate that the class invariants are respected (indeed, this is the bulk of their added value compared to a public value). It's most unusual in Getters (lazy validation is hell for debugging), though in Debug build it might be interesting to revalidate at that stage just to catch more bugs.

However, that's not what you are doing here. Your class Invariant clearly allow an optional element (like `GroupId`) yet you forbid the user to set this `GroupId` to an invalid state... Why !? It's irregular.

With regard to the Getter, there is a simple solution: Optional Types (like Boost.Optional). This way you always return without exception and yet you can provide a value... or not.